# Is there a ways for cinemachine to retarget player after it is destroyed and instantiated as a clone?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, cinemachine

I am working on a 2D platformer and I am using cinemachine to follow my player.
When a player drops off a platform under -20 y, the player is destroyed and instantiated as a clone to the spawn point as expected, but the camera is not following, as the original player is destroyed: it says *missing on the "Follow" Slot*.
Is there any way to solve it? I prefer using Destroy and Instantiate as respawning instead of teleporting the original player to the respawn point.

This is the respawn script (GameMaster)

```cs
public class GameMaster : MonoBehaviour
{

    public static GameMaster gm;



    void Start()
    {
        if (gm == null)
        {
            gm = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("GM").GetComponent<GameMaster>();
        }
    }
    public Transform playerPrefab, spawnPoint;
    public int spawnDelay = 2;

    public void RespawnPlayer() {
        //yield return new WaitForSeconds(spawnDelay);

        Instantiate(playerPrefab, spawnPoint.position, spawnPoint.rotation);
        Debug.Log("ADD SPAWN PARITCAL");
    }

    public static void Killplayer(Player player) {
        Destroy(player.gameObject);
        gm.RespawnPlayer();
    }
}
```

here is the player script if it is needed

```
public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    [System.Serializable]
    public class PlayerStats
    {
        public int Health = 100;

    }
    public PlayerStats playerStats = new PlayerStats();
    public int FallBoundary = -20;
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (transform.position.y <= FallBoundary)
        {
            DamagePlayer(1000);
        }
    }

    public void DamagePlayer(int damage) {
        playerStats.Health -= damage;
        if (playerStats.Health<=0)
        {
            Debug.Log("Kill Player");
            GameMaster.Killplayer(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *`it says missing on the "Follow" Slot, is there any way to solve it`* Yes. Reassign it programatically when you respawn the player. When you destroy and respawn the player, that's a new GameObject that is not the same as the old one, so Cinemachine doesn't know about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can cache the cinemachine inside your start method and then assign to follow the player at respawn.

Your code will become

```cs
using Cinemachine;

public class GameMaster : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static GameMaster gm;
    public CinemachineVirtualCamera myCinemachine;


    void Start()
    {
        if (gm == null)
        {
            gm = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("GM").GetComponent<GameMaster>();
        }

        myCinemachine = GetComponent<CinemachineVirtualCamera>();
    }
    public Transform playerPrefab, spawnPoint;
    public int spawnDelay = 2;

    public void RespawnPlayer() {
        //yield return new WaitForSeconds(spawnDelay);

        var newPlayer = Instantiate(playerPrefab, spawnPoint.position, spawnPoint.rotation);
        Debug.Log("ADD SPAWN PARITCAL");

        myCinemachine.m_Follow = newPlayer;
    }

    public static void Killplayer(Player player) {
        Destroy(player.gameObject);
        gm.RespawnPlayer();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must assign the new object to follow like this:

```
myCinemachine.m_Follow = spawnedPlayer;
```

Comment: How does the line above work? Does the code above makes the vcam (myCinemachine's) follow slot change to "spawnPlayer"? what specifically is the object myCinemachine and how to create the object? (I am new to Unity and Programming)